# Locate features along routes: measurement unit output?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, distance, linear-referencing

I am using ArcMap version 10.3.1:

I have a polyline (also converted to a route feature) and points layer. All points lie on the line. I want to calculate the distance each point is from either the start or end of the polyline.

I have used the Locate Feature Along Routes tool (with metres as the unit), and have not selected options to the 'keep only closest route location' and the 'use M direction offsetting'.

I get an output which makes sense for relative distances points should be from each other, but the units appear to be wrong (possibly in decimal degrees?). I am confused because the units of my map projection are in metres, i.e. when I use the 'measure' tool on the map it gives me back metre measurements.

Is there any other reason I have missed as to why the Locate Features Along Routes tool has not outputted measurements in metres?

Comment: Be sure you have projected dataset and projected coordinate system for the project.